# Resample and aggregate data according to another column value

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

My time series is something like this:

```
TranID,Time,Price,Volume,SaleOrderVolume,BuyOrderVolume,Type,SaleOrderID,SaleOrderPrice,BuyOrderID,BuyOrderPrice
1,09:25:00,137.69,200,200,453,B,182023,137.69,241939,137.69
2,09:25:00,137.69,253,300,453,S,184857,137.69,241939,137.69
3,09:25:00,137.69,47,300,200,B,184857,137.69,241322,137.69
4,09:25:00,137.69,153,200,200,B,219208,137.69,241322,137.69
```

I want to resample and aggregate the dataframe by volume, but in result, I should be able to get something like:

```
Time, Volume_B, Volume_S
09:25:00, 400, 253
```

Volume_B is aggregated volume when the **Type** is 'B', and Volume_S is aggregated when its **Type** is 'S'.

My function is something like below, but it doesn't work well.

```
data.resample('t').agg(Volume_B=(Volume=lambda x: np.where(x['Type']=='B', x['Volume'], 0)), Volume_A=(Volume=lambda x: np.where(x['Type']=='S', x['Volume'], 0)))
```

How to properly implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create the columns Volume_B (and _S) before with `np.where` like you did, then aggregate, so:

```
res = (
    df.assign(Volume_B= lambda x: np.where(x['Type']=='B', x['Volume'], 0), 
              Volume_S= lambda x: np.where(x['Type']=='S', x['Volume'], 0))\
      .groupby(df['Time']) # you can replace by resample here
      [['Volume_B','Volume_S']].sum()
      .reset_index()
)
print(res)
       Time  Volume_B  Volume_S
0  09:25:00       400       253
```

Edit, with your input like that (and aggregating on Time column), then you could also do a `pivot_table` like:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='Type', 
                values='Volume', aggfunc=sum)
   .add_prefix('Volume_')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```